# LINQ to Sql: Insert instead of Update

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am stuck with this problems for a long time now.

Everything I try to do is insert a row in my DB if it's new information - if not update the existing one.

I've updated many entities in my life before - but what's wrong with this code is beyond me (probably something pretty basic)
I guess I can't see the wood for the trees...

```
private Models.databaseDataContext db = new Models.databaseDataContext();

internal void StoreInformations(IEnumerable<EntityType> iEnumerable)
{
 foreach (EntityType item in iEnumerable)
 {
  EntityType type = db.EntityType.Where(t => t.Room == item.Room).FirstOrDefault();
  if (type == null)
  {
   db.EntityType.InsertOnSubmit(item);
  }
  else
  {
   type.Date = item.Date;
   type.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now();
   type.End = item.End;
  }       
 }
}

internal void Save()
{
 db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

**Edit:**
just checked the ChangeSet, there are no updates only inserts.
For now I've settled with

```
foreach (EntityType item in iEnumerable)
{
    EntityType type = db.EntityType.Where(t => t.Room == item.Room).FirstOrDefault();
    if (type != null)
    {
        db.Exams.DeleteOnSubmit(type);
    }
    db.EntityType.InsertOnSubmit(item);
}
```

but I'd love to do updates and lose these unnecessary delete statements.

Comment: What is `cur`? It's not defined in the code you've attached.

Comment: Can you tell us what happened when you ran this code, and what you wanted to happen instead?

Comment: it inserts a new row - regardless if type == null or not
and.
Every row should reference to a different room.

I'm writing a asp.net mvc website which displays the class (in school) that takes place in any given room.
One class can only be in one room. If eg the instructor changes, I need to update the entity - which it doesn't.
I end up with the old record intact and a new one with the correct information inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I worked out why it didn't work the way I anticipated it.

```
function Stuff()
{    
    Wrapper x = new Wrapper();
    Type a = new Type();
    InsertType(a);
    x.Type = a;
    InsertOnSubmit(x);
}

function InsertType (Type a)
{
    InsertOnSubmit(a);
}
```

since a in x is still the same a will be inserted a second time - it's still new.
Somehow I thought that they were referenced and essentially the same.

I haven't thought about why it does work when I delete the old record first. Don't want to waste any more time on this.
On to new worlds (EF4 or NHibernate)!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want `item.Room` instead of `iEnumerable.Room`?

Comment: true and I edited the question accordingly since it doesn't solve the underlying problem

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you are experiencing issues due to the problem discussed here:
[Why can't I change elements from a linq IEnumerable in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751776/why-cant-i-change-elements-from-a-linq-ienumerable-in-a-for-loop)

One way to test it would be to pass in a List of EntityType instead of IEnumerable as such:

```
internal void StoreInformations(IList<EntityType> iEnumerable)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Just tried, sadly it doesn't change anything (since I am not updating iEnumerable).
I checked everythin else too, still no luck

Comment: I guess I may have dismissed your answer a bit too soon.
Since nothing was new I only saw three inserts. But I tried to force an update - I get for each insert an update - so the original value will be updated and a new one inserted...

Comment: So have you made any progress or are you going to stick with the workaround you posted above?

In my answer I was thinking that in the section you were doing the updating, `item` was being destroyed after the foreach loop and maybe that's why `type` wasn't being updated.

Recently I've been bitten by issues with trying to do updates while working with IEnumerable<> and I resolved my issue by using IList<> in certain places.

I'm new to Linq myself, but your issue looked somewhat similar, so I thought maybe using IList in place of IEnumerable might work.  But I don't know enough to say why.

Comment: sorry I didn't comment any sooner, I ditched LinqToSql entirely - it's dead technology anyway. :)